# Does zend studio create project structure?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

When I tried the Zend Studio to create new zend framework project it creates just the folder named with project name but it's empty.

In some tutorials I've seen it creating the full structure of zend project public, application[controllers,models,views],library....

I don't have the zend server is this the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend Studio does not create the project structure with all folders. You can either do it manually by creating the folders or use the the [CLI, or command line tool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) (internally known as the console tool).

Using it you can generate the basic project [structure and add/edit structure and files.](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3811)

[image]

Comment: i use zf in windows but I've seen some tutorials showing that when you choose zend framework application the program create the needed structure without using zf!!

Comment: Well but project strucuture is not static, you can choose between several types of structure like modular application design, the CLI tool is easy to setup and I recommend you to use it if you want to work with zend framework